# Provisioning Profile after app Transfer via iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

I had an app live with my current account provisioning profiles and app identifier. Now I transferred that app to another iTunes connect account. I want to send a new version. In that case which provisioning profiles I will use? the old one or I have to create new one. Please keep in mind that app have same bundleID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After app transfer the application will have same bundleID, so you will use same bundle ID as it was before transfer, but the Team id before the bundle ID in provisioning profile will be replaced by the Team ID of new account. So you have to use the new account's (current account where app exists) provisioning profile. You will see your app with old bundle ID at provisioning portal.

Comment: Yea i experienced the same when i did that. Thanks